# How to specify default conffile?

Tags: configuration, debian, packaging

My package looks this way

```
package_name
--src
--conf
----default_configuration
--debian
----conffiles
```

I want to put `default_configuration` to `/etc/logrotate.d/` and ask a user if he wants to overwrite it when he uses `dpkg`

When I write `../conf/default_configuration /etc/logrotate.d/` to `conffiles`, `dpkg` treats it like a single file and creates a message, that it does not exist.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conffiles` is used to to describe files on the *installed* system which should be treated as config files. See [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html).  As `../conf/default_configuration` doesn't exist once the package is installed, obviously it will say that it doesn't exist.

You're also creating an invalid `conffiles` file.  The spec (see link above) says one file name per line. This is why it treats it all as a single file name.

Further, everything in `/etc` is automatically treated as a config file, so you have no reason to use `conffiles` in your package at all.  Simply install the file to `/etc/logrotate.d` (or anywhere else in `/etc`, and dpkg will treat it properly for you.

If your package isn't already installing the config file, you may want to add this to `debian/install`:

```
conf/default_configuration etc/logrotate.d
```